# Testing changes made to AOSP code (package android.media) on an emulator

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded AOSP on Ubuntu, made changes and built it for x86_64 (lunch aosp_x86_64-eng).
The changes are in package android.media.

Can I test the changes on the emulator on Ubuntu? Do I need to build the emulator?
(I am not using Android Studio. I build AOSP and start the emulator on the command line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: the framework and push the jar

```
make framework
adb root
adb remount
adb sync 
adb reboot
```

Option 2:

Full make and flash via fastboot